# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC returning NULL - why?

Tags: php, pdo

trying to write a simple PHP pagination for a hobbyist project. Stuck when trying to fetch the database query in an associative array for getting the total count so I can calculate the number of pages. Why doesn't $cnt hold any value?

```
    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM `blah`");
    $rows = $result->fetchColumn();
    echo $rows . "<br>"; // correctly echoes the number

    $rs = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cnt = $rs["cnt"];
    var_dump($cnt); // returns NULL - why? :-/

    $totalPages = ceil($cnt / $perpage);
```

Comment: `fetchColumn` already moved you to the first row in the result set. Calling `fetch()` after that will attempt to retrieve the *second* row, which doesn't exist. That's why you're getting `null`.